# Is there predefined class in java which can tell me if the Object has any value in it?

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to figure out if the result holds a low value.

for eg. -> if String then null, if `double` then `0.0` , if `int` then `0`.

```
String method = validationObject.getString("method");
                    Method invokablemethod = getMethod(method, expenseitem);

                    if (invokablemethod != null) {                      

                        Object result = invokablemethod.invoke(expenseitem);

                        if (result == null) {
                            nullFields.put(validationObject.getString("key"));
```

The explanation for the above code is as follows-:

I am trying to invoke a method on an object and result could be of any type. 
Hence, result could be `null` for `String`, `0.0` for `double` types and so on.

Now, i can create the seperate class for the same but wanted to know if there is any predefined class to achieve the same .

Thanks.

Comment: No, there is not. Thankfully, otherwise we would be in the same mess Javascript has at its hands with its concept of "truthy" values and the various "entertaining" edge-cases and surprises.

Comment: There’s a misunderstandig. An object null means: there is no object. Corresponding to double == 0.0 would be String == "", the empty String. And there are classes without a 0 value.

Comment: If we want to be precise here, `int` and `double` are not `Object`s, they are primitive types. `Integer` and `Double` on the other hand are `Object`s

Comment: @Thilo Since, I don't know JavaScript .Can't comment on that.

Comment: @Amongalen Yeah, i am referring to the wrapper Classes here, My bad.

Comment: @ChristianH.Kuhn Reflection gives you the value during the run time, based on the type  in the actual class it will give you the low-value based on the object type defined there. so it was defined as double but was not present in the invokable object . so the value will be the 0.0 in case of Double

Comment: A field in an object cannot be "not present". If you do not set a value in the constructor or initializer statement then it will start out as `null`, `false`, `0` etc.  But if you encounter those values in an object that does not mean that the field is "missing". It may very well have had a different value before and been later changed to that "low-value" again. What do you really need to do here?

Comment: Why should that method consider `null` for `String` and not the value of `isEmpty()`, which is `true` for `""`, while on the other hand, consider `0.0` as “empty” for a `Double` instead of `null`, not to speak of ignoring the `NaN`, which is literally “Not a Number”?

Answer (score -1):

No there is not.

To my understanding of your question, what you will have to do to check the returned objects value's something as below;

Once you've invoked your method (`Object result = invokablemethod.invoke(expenseitem);`), you will need to check what class the instance of the returned object (`result`) belongs to.

Then write your own logic for each instance type.

Simplest prototype would look like this;

```
Object result = invokablemethod.invoke(expenseitem);
if(result instanceOf String)
{
    ///Your logic here
}
else if(result instanceOf Integer)
{
    ///Your logic here
}
else if(result instanceOf Double)
{
    ///Your logic here
}
.
.
.
so on...
```

Comment: Yeah i know this , but i was looking for the predefined Class.